# Filter not exit in my custom Twig extension

Tags: php, symfony, filter, twig

Followed http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html to create my custom Twig filter to be used in my Symfony 2 project.

Everything seems fine but when loading the page, it says:

`The filter "tss" does not exist in AppBundle:Default:status.html.twig at line 7`

My `services.yml`:

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

My `src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php`:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilter()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('tss', [$this, 'tssFilter']),
        ];
    }

    public function tssFilter(\DateTime $timestamp)
    {
        return 'ready';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misspelled the method name. Its `public function getFilters()` not `public function getFilter()`

Comment: good catch, easy points as soon as you have [the eye](http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/335/7/9/galaxy_eye_1_by_chaostranquility_nyt-d5mpgie.jpg) 8-).

Comment: Yes, agreed. My IDE does not hint me on implementing the function in the inherited interface.